# Any tool/utility to rewrite URLs in an html page

Tags: html, nginx, lua

I am beginning to use lua especially with nginx. I need to rewrite the URLs *within* the html page i.e. let's say `<a href="http://toberewritten.com">link1</a>` should be rewritten to  `<a href="http://rewritten.com">link1</a>`

The lua html parser at  https://github.com/wscherphof/lua-htmlparser provides the URL but as far as I understand from its documentation, it will not rewrite the URL. I can perhaps reconstruct the page but was wondering if there is already a tool that would do that

Thanks for any inputs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try https://github.com/agentzh/replace-filter-nginx-module

```
location / {
    # caseless global substitution:
    replace_filter 'toberewritten' 'rewritten' 'ig';
    replace_filter_types text/plain text/css;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You could try the official http://nginx.org/r/sub_filter, which is part of an official module that's already part of nginx (although it's not built by default, so, you'd have to recompile anyways).

```
sub_filter  http://toberewritten.com    http://rewritten.com;
sub_filter_once off;
```