# http_sub_module in nginx does not seem to work

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

Im am trying to set up a reverse proxy to provide a local http service via http-ssl (https). The configuration is set up like this:

- Backend server listens on 127.0.0.1:8081 and therefore only receives connections from localhost. It serves all web pages without (!) compression.
- Frontend server (= nginx) listens on port 83 and serves data it fetches from 127.0.0.1:8081

So far this work fine in nginx. Unfortunately the backend server provides some absolute URLs like "`http://127.0.0.1:8081/....`" in the web pages it serves. And this behaviour can not (!) be changed. The nginx server therefore delivers the pages as is containing the invalid references to 127.0.0.1 by default - which is wrong by the clients point of view.

Using a sub_filter rule the web pages served should undergo a string replacement within the web page. As I can not modify the backend server the nginx server should replace `http://127.0.0.1` with a more suitable URL. But this is not working. In fact it seems that no kind of string replacement is performed at all. What ever strings I try to replace - the web page delivered to the client remains unchanged.

My nginx configuration is this:

```
server {
    listen 83 default_server;
    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081;

        sub_filter Test TEST;
        sub_filter_once on;
        sub_filter_types text/xml text/css text/javascript;
    }
}
```

Note: In this configuration I am trying to replace "Test" with "TEST" (but to no avail). "Test" is a randomly selected string found in the web page delivered by the backend web server. I use as test subject here. The real replacement should be "`http://127.0.0.1:8081/`" to "`/`" later, but even this simple test did not succeed.

Another note: In the final configuration the nginx server should serve the data using https. For tests the configuration tested and presented above does not include the SSL configuration.

`nginx -V` tells me that nginx has been compiled with the relevant modules (`--with-http_sub_module`) so everything should work, shouldn't it?

I probably do something wrong but unfortunately I can not figure out what it is exactly that I am doing wrong here. I found even two answers on stackoverflow, namely the following ones, but none of them worked:

- [Any tool/utility to rewrite URLs in an html page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20994225)
- [http_sub_module / sub_filter of nginx and reverse proxy not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31893211)

Can you help? Thanx in advance for your answers.

Comment: The ngx_http_sub_module module is a filter that modifies a response by replacing one specified string by another. What you need is rewite ... ... break; and then proxy_pass http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass http://serverfault.com/questions/379675/nginx-reverse-proxy-url-rewrite

Comment: According to your explanation the http_sub_module should do exactly what I would expect it to do: Modifying the content before delivery. But it does not: Regardles of what kind of RegEx I provide the content does not get modified.

Nevertheless thank you for mentioning "rewrite": I did not come accross any configuration possibility like that in my google searches. I will try this option soon and then give feedback if "rewrite" solved this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hello!

Have you solved this issue? I think what you need, is the http_realip module.

From nginx.org documentation:

> The **ngx_http_realip_module** module is used to change the client address to the one sent in the specified header field.
>   This module is not built by default, it should be enabled with the **--with-http_realip_module** configuration parameter.

This module is needed when your NGINX server is behind a L7 load balancer or another device that passes the client's IP address in an HTTP header.

Probably this will help